# What was this children's game show that was on morning tv?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember watching a children's game show on morning tv and I'm trying to remember what it was. I can't remember if was either on a Saturday or a Sunday morning but I do remember it was somewhere in the 90's and it was on channel 3 like other childrens shows used to be in the 90's, presumeble 1997 or 1998, and it was in the uk.

Children had to do challenges. Winners got points and losers got forfeits, which were I think eating something that wasn't tasty. Prizes and forfeits were given to challengers by a lady dressed as a maid.

The game show had 2 puppet cute mascots for entertainment; one main mascot was a small pink fluffy monster that looked like a big furball with legs. The other mascot was the other mascots sister and she looked like a big pink monster with lipstick. The small pink monster was a puppet and the sister was a human dressed up in a costume. During the show there was always an animated story about the mascot's adventures.

The prizes were always books for school, board games and an alarm clock.

If anyone does remember this show like me, please tell me because I really want to know what it was called.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be about a work of science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: @DavidW There are 2 monsters running about in the studio - does that not make this gameshow qualify?

Comment: @DannyMcG No, for the same reason any puppet or talking animals kids show is not intrinsically SFnal.

Comment: The animated interludes do suggest a possibility of SF&F elements (say, if the puppet monster mascot lived in a world of monsters (and not just creatures that are essentially just normal humans who look like monsters)).

Comment: Found on Youtube. It's something called "Eat Your Words", which was apparently on GMTV (ITV's morning show) circa 1994 (not 1997/8.) I don't often go on Movies.SE but if I see the question reposted there I'll post this as an answer with the Youtube link to back it up.

Comment: @AJM Identification questions are off-topic on Movies.SE.

Comment: @Raj Ah. Sorry. I forgot they'd banned them.